# How to point http://localhost:port to http://dummy.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-3

My development environment details:

```
Ubuntu 11.10
Rails 2.3.11
Ruby 1.8.7
```

To use third party tools such as google-analytics I need to give valid domain name.So is there any way to point my rails server port to a dummy domain so that I can use those tools in development mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this would be to set up your application to use Passenger. You could then give it a domain name like http://dummy.com and edit the `/etc/hosts` file to set up domain like this:

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 dummy.com
```

Another good solution is offered by [Tim Pope on his blog](http://tbaggery.com/2010/03/04/smack-a-ho-st.html). He has bought the domain name smackaho.st and made it a localhost wildcard. One of the people who commented on that blog posting has some something similar with a shorter domain name, lvh.me, and you can use that instead.

If we go to http://lvh.me:3000/ you’ll see the homepage of your application because lvh.me resolves to the IP address 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a manual entry into your hosts file which will redirect dummy.com to your localhost, that may get around analytics but i'm sure analytics have an option for localhost